# Эмуляция COM порта

Tags: linux, ubuntu, com-port

Есть ubuntu 16.04 которая установлена на VirtualBox. В самой машине есть один физический com порт, он прокинут в VirtualBox в режиме "хост устройство" вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще я включил 2 порта в режиме "отключен":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате на ubuntu эти порты определяются. (Но работать я так понимаю могу только с одним)

```
 $ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.004000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.772403] 00:02: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.794717] 00:03: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.816355] 00:04: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

Вопрос такой: могу ли я сделать так чтобы я мог писать в com-порт и читать из него(как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937981/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-com-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-linux)), не подключая никакое устройство (мне просто нужно эхо) и не прибегая ни к каким костылям вроде вставки скрепки в порт что бы замкнуть TX-RX.

Может ли мне в этом помочь `socat`. Насколько я понял, с помощью  него можно сделать мост с одного порта на другой, но я запутался в дебрях его настройки, был бы благодарен если кто подскажет правильную строчку.

Или `socat` для этой цели не подходит, и мне нужно что-то другое?

Comment: Там же в комментарии к ответу я вам написал куда смотреть для включения внутренней петли обратной связи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последовательный порт с точки зрения *nix-систем — это обычное терминальное устройство. Так что самое простое — создать псевдотерминал и подключиться к нему:

```
socat PIPE PTY,link=/tmp/my_pty,raw,echo=0
```

- `PIPE` — создаёт неименованную трубу между входом и выходом, по сути работает как простой эхо-ответчик
- `PTY` — создаёт псевдотерминальное устройство, к которому можно подключиться
- `link=/tmp/my_pty` — создаёт ссылку на устройство, к которой можно подключаться, как к устройству, именно его можно указывать в `open()` при открытии порта.
- `raw,echo=0` — задаёт режим работы псевдотерминала, дабы исключить изменение данных ответа.

Из отличий от настоящего порта, самое явное — отсутствие задержки при отправке/получении данных, независимо от установленного `baudrate`'а данные будут передаваться почти мгновенно и целым пакетом.

---

Из альтернатив:

- [tty0tty](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty)  — эмулирует полноценную пару соединённых друг с другом портов, в качестве эхо можно использовать тот же socat на одном из них.
- Перенаправить COM-порт в коробке на unix или tcp сокет. После чего можно использовать на этом сокете любой эхо-клиент/сервер на хосте или даже удалённой системе. В качестве клиента/сервера может выступать тот же `socat`.