# Зацикливание com порта linux

Tags: linux, com-порт

Есть ли возможность "Зациклить" com порт ?
Суть в том, что нужно локально (на одном компьютере) запустить 2 программы: одна пишет в порт, другая из него читает. Com порт существующий (не виртуальный). Когда к com порту ничего не подключено физически (провод не воткнут), данные записываются, но не считываются. Насколько я разобрался, есть 2 буфера: TX( для записи) и RX(для чтения). Если возможность настроить порт так, чтоб при записи данные сразу переносились в буфер для чтения? (Перемычка между пинами 2 и 3 (RX и TX) - не подойдет как вариант решения). Нужен именно физический com, /dev/ttyS3, например.

Comment: Ну вообще перемычка и есть оборудование на физическом порту. Чем она не подходит? Если нужно ещё "контроль контролировать", то можно и DSR-DTR и RTS-CTS соединить

Comment: Не оно? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192939/software-serial-port-loopback-on-linux

Comment: Если нужен именно реальный порт, то только перемычка... про то, чего достаточно для отладки в большинстве случаев уже писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/938514/%d0%ad%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-com-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, большинство современных портов умеют встроенный loop back, так что нет, перемычка как раз чаще не нужна. Посмотрите, например, исходники https://github.com/nsekhar/serialcheck

Comment: @0andriy, ты не прав... и при чём здесь эта утилитка? она лишь позволяет тестировать соединённые друг с другом **разные** порты, вероятно на разных машинах... и да, называть 8250 «современной» язык ни как не поворачивается...

Comment: 2OP, кстати, я не подумал... но под твоё описание вполне подходит включение `echo`-режима... не представляю, зачем тебе это может понадобиться, но любое `tty` устройство это умеет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, читай код внимательнее. А 8250 был одним из первых, где этот режим использовали, поэтому в современных практически во всех он есть.

Comment: @MBo, нет, не то. Не хотелось бы socat использовать, т.к. сторонняя утилита. Я настраивал порт через структуру termios

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я включал echo режим, также вместе с флагом clocal. Но ничего не получилось в итоге.

Comment: @0andriy, ладно, соглашусь, ещё не пробовал на практике, но похоже не прав здесь был я... напишешь ответ `OP`'у? учти, что `TIOCM_LOOP` довольно плохо документирован...

Comment: @РоманБондаренко, на вскидку не скажу, в чём проблема... вечерком попробую набросать примерчик, если не разберёшься...

Comment: с `ECHO` у меня тоже почему-то не работает =/..., хотя по логике вещей не вижу, почему это так... попозже попробую вариант с `TIOCM_LOOP`...